# user chooses background from pre-set images

Tags: android

There are 5 background images being packed in my app.  How do I make it so the user can change the background image from the 5 choices?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specified a question but I will still try to help out.
I assume your problem was not being able to set a background.

Each View on Android supports custom background. You can set it by either statically within XML as such:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
  android:layout_height = "fill_parent"
  android:background = "@drawable/bck"
></LinearLayout>
```

or programmatically as such:

```
View v = findViewById(R.id.a_view);
v.setBackground(R.drawable.bck);
```

Comment: I edited the op with a better format.  what I'm looking to do is give the user the option to choose between 5 backgrounds I have packaged in the app

Comment: Well the question is pretty wide and I should guide you to [Spinner](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html). But before that get a general perspective on [Android UI](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html)

Comment: Looking at the samples at <your-sdk-folder>\samples\ will help you about UI and EventListeners, too.

Comment: There are 5 background images being packed in my app. How do I make it so the user can change the background image from the 5 choices?